# Search for string by prefix and suffix (which may each be repeated) without backtracking regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regex for JS. following are inputs

```
blah    PREFIX hello SUFFIX blah
 blah   PREFIX PREFIX SUFFIX blah
  blah  PREFIX SUFFIX SUFFIX blah
blah    PREFIX var+2 SUFFIX blah
```

The regex should return a first group/index of the sequence

```
PREFIX hello SUFFIX
PREFIX PREFIX SUFFIX
PREFIX SUFFIX SUFFIX
PREFIX var+2 SUFFIX
```

Note: PREFIX and SUFFIX are kind of fixed. in between these words, we can have any number. of words.

I came up with this regex

```
(PREFIX(?=(?<spaces>[\s\S]+SUFFIX))\k<spaces>)
```

but this one was reported as [polynomial](https://devina.io/redos-checker)

https://regex101.com/r/YCbU0f/1 has attack string which causes more backtracking.. Can we make it safe from tool above meeting above requirements.

Comment: What your regex should do?

Comment: I updated the description with expected output. Please see..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Backtracking can be slow and vulnerable to attack strings

Have you considered a much simpler approach that gets you out of Regex vulnerabilities? What you are trying to do is fundamentally simple, so is amenable to elementary operations without the sophistication of regexes?

```js
const strings = `
PREFIX hello SUFFIX
PREFIX PREFIX SUFFIX
PREFIX SUFFIX SUFFIX
PREFIX var+2 SUFFIX

Note: PREFIX and SUFFIX are kind of fixed. in between these words, we can have any number. of words.`.split("\n")

const prefix = "PREFIX"
const suffix = "SUFFIX"

strings.forEach(s => {
  const first = s.indexOf(prefix);
  const last = s.lastIndexOf(suffix);
  if (first > -1 && last > -1 && last > first) {
    out = s.slice(first, last + suffix.length);
    console.log(out)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. It definitely works for me.

Comment: Please mark as correct. 8-)